# Write a batch file in Windows to rename folders yearwise

Tags: windows, batch-file, rename, directory

I have 123 folders. I want to rename them from 1895 to 2013. I tried:

```
for /D in (J:\Cinema\Years\*) do rename "%%k" to "%%~nx(D+1894)"
```

but I think `D` is not an integer varaible. So I've done something stupid.

Comment: You would need to provide further information. Most critically, the naming structure for your directories (a couple of explicit examples). Next minor problem is that 1895+123-1=2017, not 2013. Next issue is probably obviated by providing the directorynames - but if the target drive is FAT, the existing names may be sorted by happenstance and there's no guarantee that will be maintained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to create a variable and increment it.

This code is tested locally:

```
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

SET count=1985
FOR /D %%k IN (J:\Cinema\Years\*) DO (
    rename "%%k" "!count!"
    set /a "count+=1"
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

    set "folder=J:\Cinema\Years"

    set "counter=1895"
    for /d %%a in ("%folder%\*") do (
        echo ren "%%~fa" "!counter!"
        set /a "counter+=1"
    )
```

In your code you are missing the variable/replaceable parameter in the `for` loop (the `%%a` in this sample code). This replaceable parameter will hold the reference to the element being iterated, folder in this case (the `/d` switch asks for folders). For each of them, a rename command is executed to rename the folder to a counter, a variable that is incremented on each loop.

When batch files are executed, each line or block of code (code enclosed in parenthesis) is parsed, executed and then the process is repeated for the next line/block. At parse time, all the variable reads in the line/block are replaced with the value inside the variable before starting to execute. So, if a variable is changed inside a block and from inside the same block the changed value needs to be accessed, delayed expansion is needed, indicating the parser that the value substitution needs to be delayed until the line is executed.

This is needed for the `counter` variable. Its value changes inside the block (the `do` clause of the `for`), so, we need `enabledelayedexpansion` and the change in syntax from `%counter%` to `!counter!`, indicating the parser that this variable value will be retrieved at execution time, not parse time.

In the sample code, `ren` commands are echoed to console. If the output is correct, remove the `echo` to execute the rename operations.

The code do not check for errors. If any of the resulting folder names exist, the rename operation will fail for that folder.